# Removed repository still being showed in synaptic origin section

Tags: apt, ppa, repository, synaptic, purge

I'm sure to have correctly purged a certaing ppa: it doesn't anymore appear in `sources.list` nor in `sources.list.d` folder.

It doesn't even appear in Synaptic's repository list, but if I open the "**Origin**" section, it is always there, with the full list of its packages (all not installed, of course).

Comment: Have you tried running a `sudo apt-get update` *or* doing a package information reload (Button on the top left) in Synaptic?

Comment: of course... I thought it was obvious...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is by design. The origin section allows you to view packages by repository (origin).

Source: http://www.howtogeek.com/118665/10-package-management-operations-you-need-synaptic-for-on-ubuntu/

Just because you are no longer using it doesn't mean it doesn't exist....